# Get all your answers checked by me

Tags: word-usage

Kids were solving a few math problems. So our teacher said:

> Get all your answers checked by me.

Is there a more natural way to describe this? ( I mean without using "checked"..)
Actually he was going to tell if our answers were correct. (Maybe he'll just look at them or maybe he'll correct them with a pen).

Comment: What seems unnatural about “checked” in this sentence? More information will help us give you the best answer

Comment: There is nothing *unnatural* about *checked*.